# Nonlinear circuit v(i) function for I-V plot

Tags: voltage, transistors, theory, non-linear

I'm trying to understand how to theoretically derive the equation that could be used for plotting the I-V graph. The points of interest are `Out +` and `Out -` and the current that would flow through that branch if different loads were applied.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGvwAX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that the graph should roughly resemble the image below:

[image]

After learning that Thevenin can only be used on linear circuits, I got left without ideas.

Is it possible to theoretically approach this and have a function `u_out(i_out)` as a result?

Comment: What do you want to analyze/simulate now? The current source on the right? That's purely artificial, these elements aren't present in a real-world solar cell, so it makes no sense to muse about their characteristics.

Comment: @Janka Changed it to have no more notion about the solar cell for it isn't the question essence. I am looking for a way how to approach getting an function which would result in a IV plot.

Comment: Then put an adjustable voltage source to the left and measure the current flowing into that source. If you want a scope reading, put the scope in xy mode, use a sawtooth voltage source and measure the drop over a series resistor.

Comment: Please read the question again. In the first sentence I address the goal and motivation for the question. `I'm trying to understand how to theoretically derive the equation`

Comment: Then, the answer is: The circuit is that of a diode paralleled by a current source. Voltage over the diode is governed only by the diode characteristics and the current (set by lighting intensity). All equations are that of a silicium diode. **Look up the formulas of the silicium diode.**